# NgRx: Select multiple properties

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have an object that is saved on the store and I want to subscribe to listen some properties.

I´m using `NgRx 6.1.2` but I have a lot of questions about how listen the changes of certain state properties including *nested* properties.

My intention is use two properties to validate if load data was finished and the other properties to populate component variables and render the component,

I wrote this, but no works, since it listens to the changes of entire store and not the selected properties.

```
this.isLoading = true;
this.inicioSubs = this.store
.pipe(
  select(state => {
    return {
      temas: state.multimedia.multimedia.temas,
      series: state.multimedia.multimedia.series,
      lastSerie: state.multimedia.multimedia.lastSerie,
      lastTwoYearsSeries: state.multimedia.multimedia.lastTwoYearsSeries,
      lastTwoYearsTemas: state.multimedia.multimedia.lastTwoYearsTemas,
      loaded: state.multimedia.loaded,
      loading: state.multimedia.loading
    };
  }),
  filter(multimedia => multimedia.loaded && !multimedia.loading)
)
.subscribe(state => {
  this.multimedia = {
    temas: state.temas,
    series: state.series,
    lastSerie: state.lastSerie,
    lastTwoYearsSeries: state.lastTwoYearsSeries,
    lastTwoYearsTemas: state.lastTwoYearsTemas
  };

  this.isLoading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write selectors like this:

```
export const getMultimedia = (state: AppState) => state.multimedia;
export const getMultimedia = createSelector(
    getMultimediaState,
    multimediaState => multimedia.loading
  );
```

Or in case you are initializing with root state like this

```
StoreModule.forFeature('multimedia', reducers);
```

Then your multimedia.selectors.ts file should look like this:

```
  export const getMultimediaState createFeatureSelector<MultimediaState>('multimedia');

  export const getMultimedia = createSelector(
    getMultimediaState,
    multimediaState => multimedia.loading
  );

  export const getLoadedMultimedia = createSelector(
    getMultimediaState,
    multimediaState => multimediaState.filter(
      multimedia => multimedia.loaded && !multimedia.loading)
    );
```

With `createFeatureSelector` you can return a top level feature state.

Then, in your component file subscribe to the selector like this:

```
   public loadedMultimedia$;
   public isMultimediaLoading$;

   constructor(store) {
     this.loadedMultimedia$ = store.pipe(select(getLoadedMultimedia));
     this.isMultimediaLoading$ = store.pipe(select(getMultimediaLoadingStatus));
   }
```